# What makes Naive Bayes a better classifier for SPAM filtering/sentiment analysis rather than Decision Trees?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

- I am using the same exact data set
- Data set is split into 80 training/ 20 testing
- Multinomial-NB accuracy: 80%

  ```
    nb = MultinomialNB()
  ```
- DT accuracy: 70%

  ```
    dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
  ```
- My main question here is what makes the Naive Bayes classifier a better candidate when dealing with sentiment analysis and/or Spam filtering? What are some factors taken into account that reinforces accuracy for the NB model?
- sklearn provides up with these imports making our lives easier, however does not provide much details as to what is going on behind the scenes

Comment: I suggest you to check what Bayes Rule is, especially priors and posteriors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).